# Transform this into method that uses streams?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

Do you know how should I transform this :

```
private static Map<Integer, EmptyTile> createAllPossibleEmpyTiles() {
 Map<Integer,EmptyTile> emptyTileMap = new HashMap<Integer, EmptyTile>();
        for (int i = 0; i <64 ; i++) {
            emptyTileMap.put(i,new EmptyTile(i));
        }
        return emptyTileMap;
}
```

?

Comment: I would recomend looking at the Documentation of the [IntStream.range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) function and [hot to collect a Stream to a Map](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/collect-stream-to-map/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possibility to do this:

```
Map<Integer, EmptyTile> emptyTileMap = IntStream.range(0, 64).boxed().collect(toMap(i -> i, EmptyTile::new));
```

Answer (score 2):

So, let's examine the traditional way and try to convert it into the stream format.

```java
Map<Integer, EmptyTile> emptyTileMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    emptyTileMap.put(i, new EmptyTile(i));
}
return emptyTileMap;
```

There's a couple of things going on here.

1. We explicitly loop through the interval of [0, 64)
2. We generate tile objects based on the values of the interval
3. We maintain a map to keep all the generated tile objects

So, we can start the conversion from the very first part - the explicit loop. This can be achieved using
`IntStream.range(start, end)` function.

Next up, we will generate the tile objects based on the interval values, so:

```java
IntStream.range(0, 64)
        .mapToObj(number -> new EmptyTile(number))
```

We can use method reference here to shorten the code:

```java
IntStream.range(0, 64)
        .mapToObj(EmptyTile::new)
```

Next, we need to add those values to the map. To do this, we need `toMap` collector. It accepts
a key mapper and a value mapper (it has 2 more forms). Our key will be the generated number, 
and the value is the object itself, so, this is the final look.

```java
private Map<Integer, EmptyTile> createAllPossibleEmptyTilesStream() {
    return IntStream.range(0, 64)
            .mapToObj(EmptyTile::new)
            .collect(toMap(EmptyTile::getValue, x -> x));
}
```

Here, `x -> x` is the identity function. The value mapper is a function which accepts an EmptyTile
object and returns something else. Since we need the value to be object itself, we just return it.